# Instagram API: .caption.created_time vs .created_time

Tags: instagram-api

What use case would create a difference between `.caption.created_time` and `.created_time` in the metadata objects from the JSON response? My app has been monitoring media recent data from the [tags endpoint](https://instagram.com/developer/endpoints/tags/) for about a week, collecting 50 data points, and those two properties have always been the exact same Epoch time. However, these properties are different in the example response in Instagram's docs, albeit the difference is only four seconds. Copied below:

```
"caption": {
            "created_time": "1296703540",
            "text": "#Snow",
            "from": {
                "username": "emohatch",
                "id": "1242695"
            },
            "id": "26589964"
        },
"created_time": "1296703536",
```

Answer (score 1):

The user may have created the post with the original caption but then edited the caption and saved 4 seconds after they posted the original.  Fix a typo, etc.

Comment: So then `.caption.created_time` would be more like time last modified?

Comment: That's what I'm thinking.  I guess really the only sure fire way would be to test via a post from your own account and then check the data.

Comment: I have tested this and it does not work. I published a photo, then I edited it, and the `created_time` and `caption.created_time`  are the same.